# Windows Container, with Legacy WCF / TCP Issue

Tags: .net, wcf, containers

I've started migrating a Legacy multi-service application to a Windows Container, so we can easily move it to a new server in the near future.

This application is .Net 4.5.1, and utilizes WCF for majority of its connections. The WCF is net.tcp, with Security Mode Transport, and a Windows TCP Client Credential Type.

I have a DockerFile which uses microsoft/wcf as a base, and builds the requirements of the application on top of that, eventually adding and starting the services.

The services start correctly, I have confirmed with a netstat from within the container, as well as they have a logging mechanism which logs start and stop to a SQL Server, and that works correctly as well.

The issue is I am unable to make an inbound connection to the WCF services. I keep getting this error:

**"The server has rejected the client credentials"**

I wrote a small application to run in the container, and it just triggers a command against the same service I was testing, except from within the container it works correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't worked with containers (yet), but have you checked to see what account the container is running under?  I'm thinking something similar to IIS app pools, where the default account (AppPoolIdentity or Network Service, for example) may not have sufficient priveleges to do what it's being asked to do.

Comment: Interesting thought. It was something I was exploring as well. I came across something called [Group Managed Service Accounts], in Active Directory 2012R2+. Using that should give the container access to Active Directory to handle what it needs to. I did confirm with my test service that inside the container, it cannot query Active Directory. A couple issues with this though, our AD is not at the correct functional level and it's going to be a little difficult to get there. Also - why does the test service connect to the WCF in the container without any errors?

Comment: Ah, so within the container everything works, but the inbound connection to the container itself is being rejected?

Comment: Yup - and it seems it's the WCF service that is returning the error, because if I try other ports from the outside, there is nothing listening on the inside, so they time out.

Comment: Did you get any answers for this? I have been at it for 2 days now.

Comment: Sadly no, this work was abandoned back then. I did, however, pick it up again a couple weeks ago. This time I did it completely without Active Directory. I was running into the exact same issue, the WCF services were not receiving the inbound connections. Again I confirmed netstat inside the container and they were all working. This time I did add IIS to the container and make one of those ports available out, and IIS worked with inbound connections. When seems to suggest it's an issue with WCF somehow.